# Array of refs typescript error: Property 'getBoundingClientRect' does not exist on type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have array of refs to which I use methods while looping. However, it says error that
Property 'classList' does not exist on type 'RefObject'.
Property 'getBoundingClientRect' does not exist on type 'RefObject'.

I have added respective code for more information. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

```
categories: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'About',
      img: About,
      title: 'Problem Statement',
 }]
 const categoriesContentRef = useRef<React.RefObject<HTMLElement>[]>(
    Array(data.categories.length)
      .fill(null)
      .map(() => React.createRef())
  );

const clickHandler = (event: any) => {
    console.log(categoriesContentRef);
    console.log('Clicked');
    const id = event.currentTarget.id;
    console.log(id);
    const category = categoriesContentRef.current.filter((item) => {
      return item.classList.contains(`${id}`);
    })[0];
    console.log(category);
    if (category) {
      const categoryTop = category.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      const scrollTo = window.scrollY + categoryTop - offset;
      window.scrollTo({
        top: scrollTo,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    }
  };

const Categories: React.FC<categoriesProps> = React.forwardRef(
  ({ allCategories, clickHandler }, ref: any): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <CategoriesUlWrapper>
        {allCategories.categories.map((category, index) => {
          return (
            <CategoryLi
              ref={(elm) => (ref.current[index] = elm)}
              key={category.id}
              className={category.name}
              id={category.name}
              onClick={clickHandler}
            >
              <CategoryIcon>
                <ResponsiveImage src={category.img} alt={category.name} />
              </CategoryIcon>
              <CategoryName className="p-20-semi-bold">
                {category.name}
              </CategoryName>
            </CategoryLi>
          );
        })}
      </CategoriesUlWrapper>
    );
  }
);

<Categories
 clickHandler={clickHandler}
 allCategories={data}
 ref={categoriesContentRef}
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the reference created will be an array with ref objects not the HTMLElement itself.

An item of the array has the type **React.RefObject**, not the **HTMLElement** type, so you need to access the current property as well in order to get the HTMLElement being used.

```
const category = categoriesContentRef.current.find((item) => {
  return item.current.classList.contains(`${id}`);
});
if (category) {
  const categoryTop = category.current.getBoundingClientRect().top;
}
```

Comment: Hey @jean182 , If I do console.log(category.current). It gives undefined. 
If I do, console.log(category), I get below thing
{current: Array(5)}
current: Array(5)
0: section#About.About
1: section#Process.Process
2: section#Research.Research
3: section#Wireframes.Wireframes
4: section#User-Interface.User-Interface
length: 5
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Comment: Can you share where you're calling the clickHandler? I'm a bit confused since your category has that type, so I'm guessing there might be an issue in the clickHandler call

Comment: I have made edits to question, @jean182

Comment: Hey by looking at your code and the error, I'm pretty sure you can use current like that, in both places, see the updated answer.

Comment: By using current, the error goes away, but I cant access any properties using category.current.getBoundingClientRect().top; beacuse current turns out to be undefined.

Comment: And one more thing If I do console.log(category) I directly get whole HTML element
<section>...</section>

Comment: Which version are you using? Check this code to see that my approach is working: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-architecture-ow1ft

Comment: Also you type change the useRef type to HtmlElement[] so that is why my example is not working.

Comment: I applied your sandbox thing, turns out it worked, but while accessing dom methods eg: classList, getAttribute, it errors out 'Property 'getAttribute' does not exist on type 'RefObject<HTMLElement>'

Comment: Changing the useRef type to HtmlElement[] also throws error
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(initialValue: HTMLElement[]): MutableRefObject<HTMLElement[]>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'RefObject<unknown>[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HTMLElement[]'.
      Type 'RefObject<unknown>' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLElement': accessKey, accessKeyLabel, autocapitalize, dir, and 273 more.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(initialValue: HTMLElement[] | null): RefObject<HTMLElement[]>', gave the following error.